# Array order by date by week

Tags: php, arrays, date

I have an array which outputs the following for each day between 2 dates.

So basically it gets dates and results between 04-05-2015 and 26-05-2015 and will then arrange them under each week beginning. It will then list all 7 days in that week and then list all results found under each day.

This outputs: http://pastebin.com/2SnKMgzG

As you can see, this is fine for the first nested week but the second nested week contains the first weeks results too.

```
$loop = getUsersHoursDetail("2015-05-04","2015-05-26","3");

$new_posts = array();
$merged = array();


foreach($loop as $post) {
    $week = date('W', strtotime($post['dt']));
    $year = date('Y', strtotime($post['dt']));

    $week_start = new DateTime();
    $week_start->setISODate($year,$week);

    if( !isset($new_posts[$week_start->format('Y-m-d')]) ) {
        $new_posts[$week_start->format('Y-m-d')] = array();
    }

    $date = $post['dt'];
    if (!isset($merged[$date]))
    {
        $merged[$date] = array();
    }


    array_push($merged[$date], $post);



    $new_posts[$week_start->format('Y-m-d')] = $merged;

}
```

I have got it to split it under weeks and as such each day but i can't figure out why the second week contains the first weeks data too?

Any ideas?

Also if need be, i can upload the print_r() returned from the $loop array?

Thanks

Comment: Its really difficult to understand your question what you mean to say

Comment: What is the intention of the code? You put information in both `$merged` and in `$new_posts` and it is not very clear what you want to get.

Comment: Edited with result. Let me know if this helps. If not i'll edit and work backwards.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to group the posts by weeks and get something like this:

```
$new_posts = array(
    '2015-05-04' => array(
        array('dt' => '2015-05-04', 'name' => 'first post', 'text' => 'blah, blah', ),
        array('dt' => '2015-05-06', 'name' => 'second post', 'text' => 'blah, blah', ),
    ),
    '2015-05-11' => array(
        array('dt' => '2015-05-12', 'name' => 'third post', 'text' => 'blah, blah', ),
    ),
    '2015-05-18' => array(
        array('dt' => '2015-05-18', 'name' => 'fourth post', 'text' => 'blah, blah', ),
        array('dt' => '2015-05-22', 'name' => 'fifth post', 'text' => 'blah, blah', ),
    ),
);
```

This can be easily achieved using pieces of your existing code:

```
$loop = getUsersHoursDetail("2015-05-04","2015-05-26","3");

$new_posts = array();
$merged = array();


foreach($loop as $post) {
    $date = $post['dt'];
    $week = date('W', strtotime($date));
    $year = date('Y', strtotime($date));

    $week_start = new DateTime();
    $week_start->setISODate($year, $week);

    $week_start = $week_start->format('Y-m-d');

    // Group the posts by week in $new_posts
    if (! isset($new_posts[$week_start]) ) {
        // This is the first post of this week, initialize the week's list 
        $new_posts[$week_start] = array();
    }
    $new_posts[$week_start][] = $post;


    // Group the posts by date in $merged
    if (! isset($merged[$date])) {
        // This is the first post of the day, initialize the day's list
        $merged[$date] = array();
    }
    $merged[$date][] = $post;
}
```

Also, in `$merged` you get the posts grouped by date in a similar array.

Comment: This is amazing and pretty much nearly there! The last part is that under each day, there are results which i'd like to display. How would i go about adding those in?